# второй массив в другом порядке

Tags: массивы

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Random;

public class Ld364rmc641 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double A[]=new double[20];
    double B;
    int K,i,n;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ld");
    System.out.print("K=");
    if (sc.hasNextInt())
        K = sc.nextInt();
    else {
        System.out.println("input-output error");
        sc.close();
        return;
    }
    sc.close();
    if (K==0){
        Random r = new Random();
        i=0;
        while ( i<20){
            A[i] = r.nextDouble()*20-10;
            i++;    
        }
    }
    else { 
        i=1;
        while(i<20){
            A[0]=0.5;
            A[i]= A[i-1]+K;
            i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("A:");
    i=0;
    do{
        System.out.printf("%.2f\t", A[i]);
        if (i==9)System.out.println();
        i++;
    }
    while (i<20);   
    for (i=0; i<20; i=i+1) {
        if(i%2==0) {
введите сюда код

            B = A[i];
            A[i] = A[(i+1)/2];
            A[(i+1)/2] = B;
        }
        else {
            B = A[i];
            A[i]=A[i];
        A[i]=B;
    }




    System.out.println("\nA:");
    for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%.2f\t", A[i]);
        if (i==9) System.out.println();
    }
```

нужно зделать чтобы второй массив был в таком порядке:

A0 стал A0

A1 стал  A19

A2 стал  A1

A3 стал  A18

A4 стал  A2

A5 стал  A17

и так далее

там где написано вести код , предпоследний for , нужно поменять код , остальноe

впорядке. Может ктото делал такое ?